# I got an exception when I access to a file on AWS S3 via a PreSignedURL

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I got an exception when I try to access to a file on **Amazon AWS S3** via a `PreSignedURL`.

Here is how I generate my `PreSignedURL`:

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest getPreSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = fileKey,
    Verb = HttpVerb.GET,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
};
Uri signedUrl = new Uri(new AmazonS3Client(
    Credentials.GetCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
    .GetPreSignedURL(getPreSignedUrlRequest));
```

And here is how I do my request to Amazon Transcribe (which requires an Amazon S3 URL):

```
AmazonTranscribeServiceClient amazonTSClient =
    new AmazonTranscribeServiceClient(
        Credentials.GetCredentials(),
        RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

StartTranscriptionJobRequest transcriptionJobRequest
    = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest
    {
        TranscriptionJobName = transcriptionJobName,
        Media = new Media { MediaFileUri = signedUrl },
        MediaFormat = MediaFormat.Flac,
        LanguageCode = "en-us",
        Settings = new Settings { MaxSpeakerLabels = 2 }
    };

Task<StartTranscriptionJobResponse> transcriptionJobResponseTask
    = amazonTSClient.StartTranscriptionJobAsync(transcriptionJobRequest);
transcriptionJobResponseTask.Wait(); // A System.AggregateException is thrown here
```

Exception details:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The URI that you provided doesn't point to an S3 object. Make sure that the object exists and try your request again.)'

I have tried to access the file from my browser with the generated URL and was able to download it.

Does anyone know where the mistake could have come from?

Comment: I actually had the inverse.  Browser had “Invalid Token” error, whereas programmatic GET call worked without issue

Comment: With the same code, @openwonk?

Comment: Using the link provided in the JSON response; field called “TranscriptFileUri”, I believe, contains the PreSigned URL to the S3 file that I used.  Chrome browser produced error response in XML format; GET request (written in Go, not C#) returned JSON transcript file.